# Why does puppet check for some packages every time I run it?

Tags: puppet

Every time I run puppet on my ubuntu server, I get this:

> notice: /Stage[main]/MyCompany::Role::MyApp/Package[ncurses-dev]/ensure: ensure changed 'purged' to 'present'

Every. Single. Time. Why does it do this for this particular package, and not for others, that appear in the same code block?

```
Package { ensure => present }
package {
    [
    "openjdk-6-jre-headless", # for SOLR
    "ncurses-dev",  # for varnishstat built from buildout, used by munin
    "pkg-config",
    "nfs-common",
    "gettext", # for building PO @deployment
    "libpcre3", "libpcre3-dev", # for varnish build / to be removed
    "libevent-dev", # for beantalk buid / to be removed
    "ffmpeg", # for thumbnails
    "gpac", # contains MP4Box, for making mp4 pseudo-streamables
    ]:;
  }
```

**EDIT**: running puppet in verbose/debug mode show this:

> debug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderApt: Executing '/usr/bin/dpkg-query -W --showformat ${Status} ${Package} ${Version}\n ncurses-dev'
>
> debug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderApt: Executing '/usr/bin/apt-get -q -y -o DPkg::Options::=--force-confold install ncurses-dev'

Executing the first command gives this:

> n[DEMO]root@ucdb:~#

notice the n before the prompt

Let's admit this is a formatting problem of the debug option, here is what I get when running it with some fixes:

> /usr/bin/dpkg-query -W --showformat='${Status} ${Package} ${Version}\n' ncurses-dev
>
> unknown ok not-installed ncurses-dev

Here is what I get when running `aptitude search ncurses-dev`:

> v   ncurses-dev

The package is virtual...

Comment: Is something else removing the package? Puppet changed it from purged to present... ie it thinks its not installed. What OS/Disto are you using?

Comment: I don't see puppet saying it removes the package before... I also get this notice for other packages, on other nodes. Can't figure out why puppet thinks it is purged. I edited my message to add my distro: Ubuntu

Comment: it seems puppet doesnt think its installed, can you run puppet with --debug and post the relevant output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error appears because `ncurses-dev` is a virtual package.

```
 # apt-cache show ncurses-dev
N: Can't select versions from package 'ncurses-dev' as it is purely virtual
N: No packages found
```

You either want one of this two instead:

```
libncurses5-dev - developer's libraries for ncurses
libncursesw5-dev - developer's libraries for ncursesw
```

To know which one you're using, you may do this:

```
apt-cache showpkg ncurses-dev | sed '/Reverse Provides/,$!d'
Reverse Provides: 
libncurses5-dev 5.9-4
```